# jQuery hover firing multiple times, even for TD elements where the mouse hasn't hovered for the required duration

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have the timeout set fairly long, 888ms. And I'm being careful not to let my mouse pointer linger on more than one cell. The mouse does touch some other cells extremely briefly after I have hovered over a cell in the middle of the table and then quickly move the mouse across the adjacent cells to get outside the bounds of the table. But the mouse is on those adjacent cells for only an instant.

Yet I'm getting an alert for every cell the mouse touches on its way out of the table. It's as if once the timeout has fired, any cell whose mouseover event is firing is being treated as though it had been hovered on for the full 888ms.

The following code is inside an each() loop, which visits each of the cells in the table:

```
           cell$.hover(
            function () {
                var el = $(this);
                var delayedFunction = window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $.data(el, 'timerid', null);
                    alert("hovered" + el.attr('id'));
                }, 888);       
                $.data(el, 'timerid', delayedFunction);
            },
            function () {
                var el = $(this);
                var delayedFunction = $.data(el, 'timerid');
                if (delayedFunction != null) {
                    // Kill previously started timer
                    window.clearTimeout(delayedFunction);
                }
            }
         );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the lines `var el = $(this);` are returning new jQuery Objects each time they are invoked, so you are storing `delayedFunction` for a jQuery object that is not the same in both functions (they will be different every time either function is invoked, although they are holding the same DOM object) so you're always getting `undefined` in the second function.

You can void this, by establishing the timeout id to the actual DOM object so data is preserved, like this:

```
$.data(el[0], 'timerid', delayedFunction);//In your first function
```

And

```
var delayedFunction = $.data(el[0], 'timerid');//In your second function
```

Comment: Thanks, I had thought the data value was being stored with the underlying DOM object in any case.